# When does a falling flowerpot reach maximum speed?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, velocity, drag

I’m interested to know when a flowerpot of begonias might reach terminal velocity after falling off a high balcony. I’ve read that that a penny reaches terminal velocity after just 15 metres. I think then, it would take longer (farther) for a filled flowerpot but don’t really have a precise idea.

Could anyone please provide an approximate distance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a comment, as your question can only be answered with a formula.

the terminal velocity formula,

> v = the square root of ((2*m*g)/(ρ*A*C)).

> m = mass of the falling object.

> g = the acceleration due to gravity. ...

> ρ = the density of the fluid the object is falling through.

> A = the projected area of the object. ...

> C = the drag coefficient.

It is only possible to calculate it for the specific  pot.

To get the distance of free fall before terminal velocity is reached more calculations paricular to the specific flowerpot are necessary. [There exist calculators,](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1231475371)

Comment: Thank you Anna. I found a similar Terminal Velocity Calculator: https://www.gigacalculator.com/calculators/terminal-velocity-calculator.php

Comment: This wasn’t a homework question but relevant to some literature. A penny needs 15 metres of free fall to reach terminal velocity. A human body needs 450 metres. Therefore, we can safely assume that a flowerpot is somewhere in between and can reach terminal velocity when falling from any balcony more than 150 metres high. This flowerpot’s terminal velocity is about 46 m/s